# Laravel 8 validation input for excluding data which are not in a table, must be uppercase, and formatting id

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8

In Laravel 8, I have validation for storing data like this in **public function store_notamasuk**:

```
    Request()->validate([
            'namabarang_supplier' => 'required',
            'jumlahbarang_supplier' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        ],[
            'namabarang_supplier.required' => 'Nama barang wajib diisi!',
            'jumlahbarang_supplier.required' => 'Jumlah barang wajib diisi!',
            'jumlahbarang_supplier.numeric' => 'Jumlah barang harus angka!',
            'jumlahbarang_supplier.min' => 'Jumlah barang minimal 1!',
        ]);
```

And I have validation for storing data like this in **public function store_barang**:

```
    Request()->validate([
            'kodebarang' => 'required|unique:Barang,kodebarang|min:9|max:9',
            'namabarang' => 'required',
            'hargapenjualan' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
            'hargapembelian' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        ],[
            'kodebarang.required' => 'Kode barang wajib diisi!',
            'kodebarang.unique' => 'Kode barang ini sudah ada!',
            'kodebarang.min' => 'Kode barang harus 9 karakter dengan "-" di tengahnya!',
            'kodebarang.max' => 'Kode barang harus 9 karakter dengan "-" di tengahnya!',

            'namabarang.required' => 'Nama barang wajib diisi!',

            'hargapenjualan.required' => 'Harga penjualan wajib diisi!',
            'hargapenjualan.numeric' => 'Harga penjualan harus angka!',
            'hargapenjualan.min' => 'Harga penjualan tidak boleh 0 atau kurang dari 0!',

            'hargapembelian.required' => 'Harga pembelian wajib diisi!',
            'hargapembelian.numeric' => 'Harga pembelian harus angka!',
            'hargapembelian.min' => 'Harga pembelian tidak boleh 0 atau kurang dari 0!',
        ]);
```

In *public function store_notamasuk*, I want validation of namabarang_supplier besides of required, I want to make validation if they aren't found in Barang table (namabarang column), it occurs that what I input this, not found.

In public *function store_barang*, I want validation of kodebarang besides of like of this code, I want to make validation of kodebarang (id), its formation must be like this: XXXX-0000 (where XXXX is not number and must be letter and uppercase, and 0000 is not letter and must be numbered)

How can I do this? I still confused about making this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to your `kodebarang` field: `regex:/[A-Z]{4}-\d{4}/`

This will require the first four characters to be A-Z (lower case will not pass), then a `-` character, then 4 digits.

For the `namabarang_supplier` field, I'm not exactly clear on your requirement, but it seems you want validation to fail if the input they provide is not found in the `Barang` table searching its `namabarang` column. If that understanding is correct, then this is the rule you should use for that field: `exists:Barang,namabarang`.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel Validation there is Regex Pattern validation for Specific type of pattern.
You can check this.
[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-regex)